# Matlab Import and combine multiple dat files

Tags: matlab, loops, import

I am trying to import multiple .dat files, process them and combine into a single matrix. In this case, I need to divide each cell by its time (i.e. normalizing factor).
This example is for 2 dat files, I managed to do it, but I have a lot of files, up to data100raw, and I hope to have a loop to process everything in one go, while allowing me to set a different normalizing factor for each file.

```
data1raw = importdata('2015-04-19004-190-31.04-20140819-5sample transport-PL spectra 10s-0mm.dat')
data2raw = importdata('2015-04-19004-190-31.04-20140819-5sample transport-PL spectra 10s-2mm.dat')

%remove first column
data1raw(:,1) = []
data2raw(:,1) = []

%Enter time (i.e. normalising factor)
data1time = [5; data1raw]
data2time = [10; data2raw]

%combine
datacombine = [data1time, data2time]

%normalise
width = 2
height = 1341
for ihori = 1:width
    for iverti = 2:height
        datacombine(iverti,ihori) = datacombine(iverti,ihori) / datacombine(1,ihori)
    end
end
```

Screenshots of original data 
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nFhb.png)

and final desired product (first row is the normalising factor)
[final desired product (first row is the normalising factor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80qWe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm making two assumptions:

**1.** All your files are sequentially numbered with a skip count of 2.

**2.** The datasets have an equal number of column, a count of 1341 as I understand from your code.

You need to assign all the normalization factors to a variable, 'norm' in this case.

The code will be as follows:

```
data=(1:1341)';
norm=[n1 n2 n3 ...]; % Your normalization values

for r=0:2:200
    mname=sprintf('2015-04-19004-190-31.04-20140819-5sample transport-PL spectra 10s-%dmm.dat',r);
    mdata=importdata(mname);
    data=[a mdata(:,2)];
end
data(:,1)=[];
data=data./norm;
```

Hope this helps.